# Placing button under another div

Tags: html, css

This is probably very simple but I've been unable to figure it out. All I want to do is place the button underneath the input rows.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```css
#subscribe button {
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 9px 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f82249;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <form method="POST" action="#">
          <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="A website I want to use Cobble on is:">
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

and this is what the end result always is: 
[image]

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a larger portion of your CSS? The current snippet does not replicate the issue.

Comment: The code snippet posted in the question shows the buttons under the inputs. Can you make an example with your CSS/HTML? https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/ .. Looks like HTML is fine. But something in your CSS is changing how it aligns.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just remove the col-auto class in the div wrapping you button or remove that div alltogether? The button should be a block level element by default. If that fails add display: block to the css styles

Comment: try add `<br />` before the submit button. lazy solution though since you haven't shared the proper information

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this and that's also one of the tough things to learn using CSS. This is not an answer, but I do encourage you to use Flexbox instead. It's much easier. Have a look at this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Are you using twitter bootstrap? If so here are the docs for the grid system. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I don't see most of your CSS classes in your code. Also, your HTML does not have an element with `id="subscribe button"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all three form elements inside this div:

`<div class="form-row justify-content-center">`

Make another div just like that one and move the button inside it. In fact, it looks like you want each of those elements in its own "form-row" div. The only reason the two text inputs are on different lines is because they take up the whole row and they're wrapping.